# c++ descending order with respect to second column

Tags: c++, sorting

Text file where the data is as follows:

```
0 320.77
1 100.44
2 117.66
3 541.55
```

The data is sorted with respect to the first column but I want to sort it with respect to the second column and in descending order.

The output should be as follows:

```
3 541.55
0 320.77
2 117.66
1 100.44
```

Comment: I used vectors but it is scolding me

Comment: A vector (containing `pair<int,double>` or an equivalent structure) is what you want, along with a predicate for `std::sort` that compares the second field. What did you try, and what went wrong?

Comment: yes, we need sample code to fix please

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to sorting a file by the second data type, i would give code but this seems to be a homework problem, so here is an explanation of how i solved it:

- read the line into a string
- iterate to the second number by skipping to the next space
- grab the second number from the string and place it in a separate string, then atoi() the string to get an integer
- sort the string using the integer in a sort function then call the function in `std::sort` of `qsort()`

Answer (score 0):

I think that would not hurt @laky college performance now if I entertain myself a bit and provide an answer.

```
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using Entry = std::pair<int, float>;
using Storage = std::vector<Entry>;

void dump(const Storage& storage)
{
    for(auto& [i, v] : storage)
        std::cout << i << " " << v << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    std::stringstream input;
    input.str("0 320.77\n1 100.44\n2 117.66\n3 541.55\n");

    Storage storage;

    for ( /* read 'file' into vector storage for processing */
        Entry entry; 
        input >> entry.first >> entry.second && input.good();
        )
    {
        storage.push_back(std::move(entry));
    }

    std::cout << "Original data:\n";
    dump(storage);

    std::sort(storage.begin(), storage.end(), 
        [](Entry l, Entry r) /* sorting predicate */
        {
            return l.second > r.second;
        });

    std::cout << "Sorted data:\n";
    dump(storage);

    return 0;
}
```

on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YefYqdTe7)